# Can you create accounts with less lamports than the rent-exempt minimum?

Tags: account, rent, lamports

Accounts on Solana are considered rent-exempt if they hold at least the cost of their rent for 2 years (based on the size of the account's data).

Is it possible to create an account that's not rent-exempt?

In the program code, I'm calculating rent using the following experiment:

```
let lamports_required_one_year = (Rent::get()?).due_amount(account_span, 1.0);
let lamports_required_for_exemption = (Rent::get()?).minimum_balance(account_span);
```

Then I'm hitting the System Program with a CPI using `system_instruction::create_account()`.

I can create an account successfully with `lamports_required_for_exemption` as the lamports deposited, but if I use `lamports_required_one_year` I get the following:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Transaction leaves an account with a lower balance than rent-exempt minimum
```

You can also throw the same error from the CLI if you try to airdrop less than the rent-exempt amount to a brand new keypair.

So I'm wondering - if this method blocks creation of an account with less than the 2-year exemption requirement, how do you create an account with less than 2 years' of rent?

I'm also curious - since the rent exemption is fairly inexpensive - what is the use case for non-rent-exempt account creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the [require accounts to be rent-exempt feature activation](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/22292), no accounts can be created with less rent than the 2 year rent exemption requirement.

All accounts created previous to the feature activation are unaffected.

See the note in the [documentation](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent).

Comment: after it's been created, is it possible to decrease the amount so that it's no longer exempt?

Comment: No, it is not possible to decrease below rent exemption

Comment: does this mean it's no longer possible to delete accounts? I was under the impression that I just had to transfer all lamports out of the account to "close" it

Comment: @coco please make this another question. Would be great help for those looking for that answer