# Runtime Error: "InvalidRentPayingAccount"

Tags: rent, error, runtime

Why am I getting this error? This is the runtime error version of [Can you create accounts with less lamports than the rent-exempt minimum?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/255/can-you-create-accounts-with-less-lamports-than-the-rent-exempt-minimum?rq=1)

Comment: please elaborate the question with what you were doing when you got the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this was merged in https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/24049 you need to leave 2 years worth of base rent in an account, which is currently 890880 lamports. You can check with `solana rent 0 --lamports`

Comment: the cited rent-exempt reserve balance is only accurate for accounts with 0-sized `data` fields. accounts that carry data will have a higher requirement