# Solana rent account questoin

Tags: account, associated-token-account, rent, account-data

I have a question. If I hold solana token on my wallet - do I need to pay a rent for my account on chain ? I've red official documentation and I see that there is a garbage collector in solana chain and if I have not enough sol on my account(token account) - It will be removed from chain and I'll lose my money(token) ???

E.g.
I have wallet(phantom on devnet)
My base address is HCrtG3YpbnC2YX4wDPgu12xDBa2FNVqqZ1yvob5kUp6o
Also I got test tokens to my token Account 4HQ6DLeMyvSdHSUbLUtyBLvzR1PbPdgSsrF1X7edCiJK

questions:

1. If I don't have sol on base address - will my token account will be removed with my token ?
2. are my base and token account - 'Data accounts' ? System owned account OR PDA ?
3. What exactly address I need to topup with SOL ? base address or token addres ?

Comment: The account that you get created already accounts for the rent. So you're safe.
2. Your base account is owned by the system program, while your token account that holds the actual token is owned by the token program. Yes, that's a PDA.
3. You topup your base address and the token account that hold your token (called the ATA - Associated Token Account) gets created as rent exempt.

Comment: All newly created accounts are required to be rent exempt: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/255/can-you-create-accounts-with-less-lamports-than-the-rent-exempt-minimum

Currently, you can think of "rent" on Solana more like a "deposit" that can be refunded at a later time

Comment: @munanadi, thank you for the reply. So I need to topup my base account with 0.00203928 to exempt it from rent fee. Do I need to do it per ATA or totally 0.00203928 for all my ATA's ? I mean if I have 2 or more tokens on my base account - do I need to multiply 0.00203928 with count of my ATA's ?

Comment: @john, thank for your reply. But how long new account is newly created from point of solana blockchain ? 1 epoch or more ?